# How to run Python server in Kubernetes

Tags: python, django, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have the following `Dockerfile` which I need to create an image and run as a `kubernetes` deployment

```
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.7

FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1


ARG USERID
ARG USERNAME

WORKDIR /code

COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY manage.py ./

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
RUN useradd -u "${USERID:-1001}" "${USERNAME:-jananath}"

USER "${USERNAME:-jananath}"

EXPOSE 8080

COPY . /code/

RUN pwd 
RUN ls

ENV PATH="/code/bin:${PATH}"
# CMD bash

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python"]
# CMD ["manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

And I create the image, tag it and pushed to my private repository.

And I have the `kubernetes` manifest file as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    tier: my-app
  name: my-app
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      tier: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        tier: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app      
        image: "<RETRACTED>.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/my-ecr:webv1.11"
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        args:
          - "manage.py"
          - "runserver" 
          - "0.0.0.0:8080"                     
        env:
          - name: HOST_POSTGRES
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: HOST_POSTGRES
                name: my-app  
          - name: POSTGRES_DB
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: POSTGRES_DB
                name: my-app
          - name: POSTGRES_USER
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: POSTGRES_USER
                name: my-app
          - name: USERID
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: USERID
                name: my-app
          - name: USERNAME
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                key: USERNAME
                name: my-app                

          - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                key: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
                name: my-app

        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080

        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 1000m
            memory: 1000Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 00m
            memory: 1000Mi
```

When I run the deployment above, the pod kills everytime and when I try to see the logs, this is all I see.

```
exec /usr/local/bin/python: exec format error
```

This is a simple `django` python application.

What is interesting is, this is working fine with `docker-compose` as below:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
  web:
    build: 
      context: .
      args:
        USERID: ${USERID}
        USERNAME: ${USERNAME}
    command: manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: What hardware are you using to build the image?  What's running in the cluster?  (Are you building on an ARM-based MacOS host, but running on an x86-based cluster?)

Answer (score 1):

Try to inspect your image architecture using

```
docker image inspect <your image name>
```

If you see something like,

```
"Architecture": "arm64",
"Variant": "v8",
"Os": "linux",
```

which is different from your cluster architecture. Then you must build your image on a machine with the same architecture as your cluster.